# How to define Boolean class using boost, the possible value should be TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, boost

I am trying to implement the API for Boolean, I need to implement KMboolean class, possible value should be true or false.

Is there any other way to  implement Boolean(API) functionality using defined class. please help me to resolve my issue.

Here is my snippet of code:

```
typedef KMBoolean;
```

I am new to API implementation, I am not sure my way is right or wrong, Anyone please help me to implement in general way to define Boolean functionality.

I got this thing from internet, i need to change instead of **struct to class** and should make it wrapper class. anyone please help

```
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
#include<iostream>

template<bool C>
struct Boolean
{
};

typedef Boolean<true>  true_;
typedef Boolean<false> false_;
int main()
{
}
```

i got this from internet, i dont know much about this. is it possible to do like this ?. please help

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Why can't you just use `bool`. Please state your goal (why are you trying to do this) and a desired usage.

Comment: also your snippet of code is nowhere near a valid C++ syntax.

Comment: i am implementing libraries for boost,  i need a class which should perform Boolean functionality, for that i used "typedef KMBoolean". I think now its clear.

Comment: not really no, it's not clear. " i need a class which should perform Boolean functionality" is not clear what you mean by that. Give an example why you need that and we will understand what you need. Where do you need to use to use such a class? "for that i used `typedef KMBoolean`" that's also not clear because `typedef KMBoolean` is not valid C++ code and as such it tells us nothing.

Comment: I am working on library replacement for that i need equivalent boost library code, there they defined their own class to implement Boolean functionality using typedef, i know my code is wrong, please suggest to correct or is my way is completely wrong ?. or Is it possible to write wrapper class for Boolean?. please suggest.

Comment: I suggest starting with a simpler project. It doesn't make much sense starting to create replacement libraries for boost when you lack basic C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

> am working on library replacement for that i need equivalent boost
>   library code

The `C++11` equivalent (more or less) of `boost::mpl::bool_` is [`std::integral_constant<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) which because it is commonly used even has a template alias `std::bool_constant` with the typedefs `std::true_type` - equivalent of `boost::mpl::true_` and `std::false_type` - equivalent of `boost::mpl::false_`.

So you really don't need to implement anything, just use `std::bool_constant`